# How to set "to" field (in an email header) to a group email address?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid in Node.js to send emails to a group of people. THe list is something we maintain on our website. I want the `to` (aka recipient) field in the email header to show the group email address (e.g., `my_group@my_website.com`), instead of the recipient email address (e.g., `bob@gmail.com`). This allow us to separate direct emails from group emails.

In other words, if I receive an email from the group, it should be addressed to the group (e.g., `my_group@my_website.com`) instead of me in the email header.

When we used Google Groups, we would get the email sent to `[group_email]@googlegroups.com`, instead of my email address. Below are examples of what happens when an email is sent through Google Groups. I would like some help on replicating that.

This image shows the information associated with a Google Groups email I received. The `to` field is set to the Google Groups email address, instead of my Gmail address.
[image: Gmail email info]

I thought it might be just a Google thing, but my Aol email also displays the Google Groups email as for the `to` field.
[image: Aol email info]

This is how we are currently sending the email. I understand I can set the `to` field to anything. However, if I change that to the group email (e.g., `my_group@my_website.com`), where would we be putting the email addresses of the recipients?

```
 return sgMail.send({
    to: recipient,
    from: DEFAULT_SENDER,
    subject: renderedMessage.subject,
    html: renderedMessage.html,
    text: renderedMessage.text,
    mailSettings: MAIL_SETTINGS
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. You just need to BCC (or CC) all the recipients and set the `to` field to the group email address.

It would look like:

```
 return sgMail.send({
    to: "my_group@mywebsite.com",
    bcc: recipients,
    from: DEFAULT_SENDER,
    subject: renderedMessage.subject,
    html: renderedMessage.html,
    text: renderedMessage.text,
    mailSettings: MAIL_SETTINGS
  });
```